# awk function does not allow to return

Tags: awk, gawk

i have functions in my awk script to parse lines contains certain words/characters

```
function tohyphen (o) {
        split ($0,a,"to[-_]")
        split (a[2],b,"-")
        k=b[1]
        p=b[2]
        return k
}

function tospace (o) {
        split ($0,a,"to ")
        split (a[2],b,"-")
        k=b[1]
        p=b[2]
        return k
}

funtion pipe (o) {
        split ($0,a,"|")
        split (a[2],b,"-")
        x=b[1]
        y=b[2]
        return x
        #return x
}
{
#if (match ($0, /to[-_]/))
if ($0 ~ /to[-_]/)
        print "found to- for interface ", $1, " is ", tohyphen($0), "is ",p, " is ", $1="",$0

else if ($0 ~ /to /)
        #(match ($0, /to /))
        print "found to  for interface", $1, " is ", tospace($0), "  is ", p, " is ", $1="",$0
else if ($0 ~ /\|/)
#       pipe($0)
        print "found to  for interface", $1, " is ",topipe($0), "  is ", y, " is ", $1="",$0
else
        print $1, $1="",$0
}
```

in the third function which just searches for a match to pipe it does not allow me return anything, giving me the error return is outside of function. 
any idea what could be the problem or any other way for me to run this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try spelling **function** correctly! You have funtion not function. Are you using an editor with syntax highlighting for `awk`? You can see from stackoverflows markup that funtion is not a reserved word.

Comment: thank you so much, i have slapped myself for this, took me so long to figure how to write this script that i did not see something so basic.was using nano for this but it does not highlight the function keyword

Comment: You should go with emacs or vi for editing source files, it will make your life easier and you will debug these issue quicker. You should accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it to show your question is solved.

Comment: tick marked , thanks again this was my first question on stackoverflow and yes i think a vi tutorial is the next thing im going to read.